# How to find which RecyclerView is crashing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an app with about 10 RecyclerViews. One of my users is experiencing a crash that spits the following stack trace. But problem is when I ask the user to explain. Where he claims to be seeing the crash is strange as there is no RecyclerView or ListView near there. How do I identify which RecyclerView is causing this issue? Here is the trace I am getting from Crash report.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.java:1613)
       at android.view.View.canScrollVertically(View.java:12835)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS.canScrollVertically(ViewCompatICS.java:35)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:1253)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:1695)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.canChildScrollUp(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:643)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1960)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NullPointerException:` Will be thrown if you try to use any **object** which is **not initialized**.

---

**Simple Example :**

Say you have class called **ClassA** which is having some function called **myFunction()**

Below is the **wrong code** that will throw you Exception

```
ClassA objectA;
objectA.myFunction();
```

Since you did not initialize anything in objectA (Which is currently null), it is throwing you `java.lang.NullPointerException:`

So the **correct code** is

```
ClassA objectA=new ClassA();
objectA.myFunction();
```

---

Now it will work.. Like this, You would have **missed some initialization** of any class ( Ex. RecyclerView or Adapter or LinearLayout). So this is the explanation for that Exception. Hope you understand it.

If you **can't identify** where you did mistake, use `Log.d("MY_TAG","Some text here");` between each line (or each 5 lines). Find which Log didn't executed and there should be a problem.

Good luck.. (:

Answer (score 1):

Put a `Log.d` instruction in each adapter and check de LogCat.

```
private static final String LOGTAG = "Logs";


 Log.d(LOGTAG, "MSG");
```

But yout Error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
```

Will fix if you change this in your LinearLayoutManager and RecyclerView:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Before use adapter:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This does make sense. So +1. I will know in a few days if it worked. Thanks.